# Invoicing in Word document

Tags: vba, excel, ms-word

I'm trying write a VBA script to multiply to figures which exist in a table in ms word.

So far I've managed to do the below but the value of b appears as £11,000 in the document and when I message it out it always returns it as 0.

I'd like to get the value of b as 11000 so I can multiply, any ideas or already written code would be great.

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()

    Dim t1 As Table
    Dim a As Double
    Dim m, b As Currency

    ' first table
    Set t1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    a = Val(t1.Cell(5, 3).Range.Text)
    a = a/100

    b = Val(t1.Cell(7, 4).Range.Text)
    'b = CCur(t1.Cell(7, 4).Range.Text)   **I tried this but didn't work
    MsgBox b

    m = a * b
    t1.Cell(5, 4).Range.Text = Format(m, "Currency")

 End Sub
```

Comment: m is not defined as currency and I think you think it is
Val can get confused if the cell text is formatted, you may need to Replace the comma and currency symbols

Comment: how do I get the cell contents in a variable to start replacing the comma and the currency symbol?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code was perfect - until you tried to put icing on the cake. :-)
`Dim a As Double, b As Double` This is because you don't want to multiply apples with oranges.
`m = a * b` gives the correct result, but converted to Currency which basically divides by 100. But perhaps that is done in this line, `t1.Cell(5, 4).range.Text = Format(m, "Currency")`. I don't know.
I suggest to declare m As Double and format the result like `Format(m, "#,##0.00")`

Here is the complete suggested code.

```
Private Sub Calculate_Click()

    Dim a As Double, b As Double, m As Double
    Dim Ccy As String

    With ActiveDocument.Tables(1)             ' first table
        a = CellValue(.Cell(5, 3))
        b = CellValue(.Cell(7, 4), Ccy)
        m = a * b / 100
        If Ccy = "" Then Ccy = ChrW(163)
        If Len(Ccy) > 1 Then Ccy = Ccy & " "
        .Cell(5, 4).range.Text = Format(m, Ccy & "#,##0.00")
'        .Cell(5, 4).range.Text = Format(m, "Currency")
    End With
End Sub

Private Function CellValue(Target As Cell, _
                           Optional Ccy As String) As Double

    Dim Numbers As String
    Dim Txt As String, Ch As String
    Dim i As Long, n As Long

    Txt = Replace(Trim(Target.range.Text), Chr(13), "")
    n = Len(Txt)
    Do While i < n
        i = i + 1
        Ch = Mid(Txt, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Ch) Then Exit Do
    Loop
    If i Then Ccy = Trim(Left(Txt, i - 1))

    Txt = Mid(Txt, i)
    n = Len(Txt)
    For i = 1 To n
        Ch = Mid(Txt, i, 1)
        If IsNumeric(Ch) Or (Ch = ".") Then Numbers = Numbers & Ch
    Next i
    CellValue = Val(Numbers)
End Function
```

ChrW(163) is the £ sign. I have added it into the number format for the output. The difference between using this  line or the one with "Currency" as format is that the "Currency" format is defined in the Regional settings" while the other line defines it where you see it.

The function `CellValue` will pick up the currency used in the price cell and apply it to the total cell. If the currency is a multi-character abbreviation (like GBP) a space will be added. If no currency was given £ will be used, without space.

Comment: Thank you for your reply but I think the issue is with this below line as "b" always returns as 0 so when you multiply it to "a" its returning 0. "b" should have 11000 in it.

    `b = Val(t1.Cell(7, 4).Range.Text)
     MsgBox b`

Comment: I tested your code. It returns the correct value. However, I now suspect that you might have a currency symbol in the Word table. The Val function needs a purely numeric string or will return 0. Remove the £ sign from the number in the cell and your code will work fine. You can remove it in the cell or using VBA when you convert the string in the cell to a value.

Comment: I agree and you are correct, there is a £ sign as well as a comma. Can you advise how to remove the £ sign and a a comma. I've tried not using Val but get other errors for using .range etc.

Comment: Dim Price As String:
    Price = Trim(t1.Cell(7, 4).Range.Text):
    Price = Replace(Price, ",", ""):    b = Val(Mid(Price, 2))

Comment: That worked perfectly. I take it there is no generic find and replace function as I need to remove the commas as well.

Comment: The Replace function, as employed above, replaces all commas with nothing.

Comment: Thank you for selecting my solution. I have put it together in a slightly better presentation and amended my origin al post accordingly. The function `CellValue` treats both input numbers in the same way. I'm not sure about the division by 100 in the calculation of the total.

Comment: Last night I posted code in the CellValue function which would alter the amount if no currency sign was present, such as in the quantity. My apologies. I have re-written the function and added extraction of the currency as a bonus.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this is an interesting question. In general, if you want to multiply 70066 eur and 52 cents by 10, this is how it would look like:

[image]

In my settings, I am using `,` as a decimal separator and `.` as a thousands separator. Thus, I replace the `,` with a `.` and I ignore the `.` at the beginning. Like this:

```
Replace(Replace(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, ".", ""), ",", ".")
```

The whole code looks like this:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub TestMe()

    Dim t1  As Table
    Dim a   As Currency
    Dim m   As Currency
    Dim b   As Currency

    Set t1 = ActiveDocument.Tables(1)

    With t1
        a = Val(Replace(Replace(.Cell(1, 1).Range.Text, ".", ""), ",", "."))
        b = Val(Replace(Replace(.Cell(1, 2).Range.Text, ".", ""), ",", "."))
        m = a * b
        .Cell(2, 1).Range.Text = Format(m, "Currency")
    End With

End Sub
```

It multiplies 70066,52 Eur by 10 and it returns 700665,20 Eur.

Comment: I think this is so simple as to be complicated. Better to switch the separators in a dedicated function and deal with non-numeric characters in another. In this question, however, the problem of having a comma as decimal separator didn't come up.